# Query takes too long if i include a column in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Below is the query which i need to optimize:

```
DECLARE @Power VARCHAR(10), @Button VARCHAR(10), @Casing VARCHAR(10), @Screen VARCHAR(10)
SELECT @Power = ActivityId FROM t_Activity WHERE ActivityName = 'PhonePowersUp?'
SELECT @Button = ActivityId FROM t_Activity WHERE ActivityName = 'T/S and Buttons functioning OK?'
SELECT @Casing = ActivityId FROM t_Activity WHERE ActivityName = 'Casing - no major defects?'
SELECT @Screen = ActivityId FROM t_Activity WHERE ActivityName = 'LCD works OK?'

SELECT
    HQ.HandsetQuoteId [HandsetQuoteId], SS.Name [quote_status], HQ.QuoteDate [Quote Date], INS.DateInspected [DateInspected], PA.IMEI [IMEI_Quoted],
    PA1.IMEI [IMEI_Inspected],  INS.Grade [Grade], PB.PackageBoxName [PackageBoxName], CC.Name [ContactChannel], PhnBrd.Name [Brand], PM.ModelName [ModelQuoted],
    PM1.ModelName [ModelInspected], U.FirstName [FirstName], U.Surname [Surname], U.Username [Username], UW.WarehouseId [WarehouseId], W.Name [Warehouse Name],
    HQA.Value [Original Quote Value], HQ.QuoteValue [Quote Value], INS.InspectionValue [InspectionValue], HQ.AgreedValue [Agreed Value], CUS.FirstName [Store Name],
    DATEDIFF(DAY, HQ.QuoteDate, GETDATE()) [Quote Age],
    [ST_POWER] = CASE WHEN (CHARINDEX(','+ @Power +',', ','+PAR.Ok+',') > 0) THEN 'YES' WHEN (CHARINDEX(','+ @Power +',', ','+PAR.Fault+',') > 0) THEN 'NO' ELSE NULL END,
    [ST_BUTTONS] = CASE WHEN (CHARINDEX(','+ @Button +',', ','+PAR.Ok+',') > 0) THEN 'YES' WHEN (CHARINDEX(','+ @Button +',', ','+PAR.Fault+',') > 0) THEN 'NO' ELSE NULL END,
    [ST_CASING] = CASE WHEN (CHARINDEX(','+ @Casing +',', ','+PAR.Ok+',') > 0) THEN 'YES' WHEN (CHARINDEX(','+ @Casing +',', ','+PAR.Fault+',') > 0) THEN 'NO' ELSE NULL END,
    [ST_Screen] = CASE WHEN (CHARINDEX(','+ @Screen +',', ','+PAR.Ok+',') > 0) THEN 'YES' WHEN (CHARINDEX(','+ @Screen +',', ','+PAR.Fault+',') > 0) THEN 'NO' ELSE NULL END,
    st_deduct = PAR.PercentageDeduction, wt_deduct = MAX(APD.PercentageDeduction)
FROM t_Inspection AS INS
INNER JOIN t_HandsetQuote                   HQ      ON HQ.HandsetQuoteId = INS.HandsetQuoteId
INNER JOIN t_QuoteHeader                    QH      ON QH.QuoteHeaderId = HQ.QuoteHeaderId
INNER JOIN t_Customer                       CUS     ON CUS.CustomerId = QH.CustomerId
INNER JOIN t_ContactChannel                 CC      ON CC.ContactChannelId = CUS.ContactChannelId
INNER JOIN t_PackageBoxHandset              PBH     ON PBH.HandsetQuoteId = HQ.HandsetQuoteId
INNER JOIN t_PackageBox                     PB      ON PB.PackageBoxId = PBH.PackageBoxId
INNER JOIN t_StockStatus                    SS      ON SS.StockStatusId = HQ.StockStatusId
INNER JOIN t_PhoneAudit                     PA      ON PA.PhoneAuditId = HQ.QuotePhoneAuditId
INNER JOIN t_PhoneModel                     PM      ON PM.PhoneModelId = PA.PhoneModelId AND     PA.PhoneAuditId = HQ.QuotePhoneAuditId
INNER JOIN t_PhoneBrand                     PhnBrd  ON PM.PhoneBrandId = PhnBrd.PhoneBrandId
INNER JOIN t_PhoneAudit                     PA1     ON PA1.PhoneAuditId = HQ.InspectionPhoneAuditId
INNER JOIN t_PhoneModel                     PM1     ON PM1.PhoneModelId = PA1.PhoneModelId AND PA1.PhoneAuditId = HQ.InspectionPhoneAuditId
INNER JOIN t_PhoneBrand                     PhnBrd1 ON PM1.PhoneBrandId = PhnBrd1.PhoneBrandId
INNER JOIN t_User                           U       ON INS.InspectorId = U.UserId
INNER JOIN t_UserWarehouse                  UW      ON U.UserId = UW.UserId
INNER JOIN t_Warehouse                      W       ON UW.WarehouseId = W.WarehouseId
LEFT JOIN t_HandsetQuoteAdditionalInfo      HQA     ON HQ.HandsetQuoteId = HQA.HandsetQuoteId AND HQA.KeyName = 'OriginalQuoteValue'
LEFT JOIN t_PhoneAuditRetail                PAR     ON PAR.HandsetQuoteId = HQ.HandsetQuoteId
LEFT JOIN t_HandsetQuoteActivity            HQA1    ON HQA1.HandsetQuoteId = HQ.HandsetQuoteId AND HQA1.ActivityTestOK = 0 AND HQA1.ActivityStartTime = (
                                        CASE
                                            WHEN ((SELECT Count(1) FROM t_HandsetQuoteActivity WHERE  HandsetQuoteId = HQA1.HandsetQuoteId AND ActivityStartTime <= QH.Cache_QuoteAcceptedDate AND ActivityId = HQA1.ActivityId) > 0)
                                            THEN (SELECT Max(ActivityStartTime) FROM t_HandsetQuoteActivity WHERE HandsetQuoteId = HQA1.HandsetQuoteId AND ActivityStartTime <= QH.Cache_QuoteAcceptedDate AND ActivityId = HQA1.ActivityId GROUP BY HandsetQuoteId, ActivityId)
                                        ELSE
                                            (SELECT Min(ActivityStartTime) FROM  t_HandsetQuoteActivity WHERE HandsetQuoteId = HQA1.HandsetQuoteId AND ActivityStartTime >= QH.Cache_QuoteAcceptedDate AND ActivityId = HQA1.ActivityId GROUP BY HandsetQuoteId, ActivityId)
                                        END)
LEFT JOIN t_Activity_PercentageDeduction    APD     ON APD.ActivityId = HQA1.ActivityId AND APD.ContactChannelId = CUS.ContactChannelId AND APD.ContactChannelId = CC.ContactChannelId
WHERE Ins.DateInspected > GETDATE()-90
GROUP BY HQ.HandsetQuoteId, SS.Name, QH.CreatedDate, INS.DateInspected, PA.IMEI, PA1.IMEI, INS.Grade, PB.PackageBoxName, CC.Name, PhnBrd.Name, PM.ModelName, PM1.ModelName,
U.FirstName, U.Surname, U.Username, UW.WarehouseId, W.Name, HQA.Value, HQ.QuoteValue, INS.InspectionValue, HQ.AgreedValue, CUS.Firstname, HQ.QuoteDate, PAR.Ok, PAR.Fault,
PAR.PercentageDeduction
```

And, after properly debugging it, I came to know that when i remove `wt_deduct = MAX(APD.PercentageDeduction)` from the select list, the query executes with in less than a minute.

But, however i am not able to figure it out, that whats wrong with the column `APD.PercentageDeduction`, because when i include it in the select list, my query stucks and becomes too slow and takes `15 minutes` to run and excluding it from the select list makes the query to run with in `30 seconds.`

**Additional Information:**
Table -> `t_Activity_PercentageDeduction` contains only 400 records, column `PercentageDeduction` is of `Decimal` datatype.

Please let me know if you want some other information too.

Comment: Showing both execution plans would dramatically increase my interest in actually tackling the problem.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens sure please wait, let me go for it..

Comment: @PieterGeerkens where should i upload the execution plan, because its a long file of 1.5 MB

Answer (score 0):

If Im not mistaken you are only joining to that table in order to get that MAX value, and by adding this Max value, you are also having to do all the grouping. So there is actually quite a difference in the queries.

I would suggest using a co-related sub-query to get this piece of data.

remove the left join

```
    LEFT JOIN t_Activity_PercentageDeduction    APD     ON APD.ActivityId = HQA1.ActivityId AND APD.ContactChannelId = CUS.ContactChannelId AND APD.ContactChannelId = CC.ContactChannelId
```

and set wt_deduct = to the new co-related sub-query

```
wt_deduct = (select MAX(PercentageDeduction) from t_Activity_PercentageDeduction 
                 where ActivityId = HQA1.ActivityId 
                 AND ContactChannelId = CUS.ContactChannelId 
                 AND ContactChannelId = CC.ContactChannelId)
```

And you can remove all the grouping that is no longer required too.

Comment: can you please help me out, how to write such query

Comment: @HarshSharma - try that. it might need tweaking. obviously I don't have anything to test against.